# Spinner - Quebra de linha na lista

Tags: java, android

Ao abrir o `Spinner`, tem algumas opções que são grandes, então por padrão ele coloca pontos ".." no final do item.

Existe alguma `opção padrão do Spinner` para a quebra automática ou teria que ser criado um `xml de layout` para isso ?

Answer (score 0):

Nao existe assim nenhuma opçao direta para meteres multi lines sem extenderes o spinner e fazer override e apanhar certas views.

Acho que o mais facil é criares um xml com o layout que queres para representar uma linha e depois meter esse xml como adapter do spinner.

spinner_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:text="@+id/TextView01" 
   android:id="@+id/TextView01"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textSize="17sp"/>
```

Depois crias o array adapter e colocas lá uma lista de dados com o nome listaDeDados:

```
ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_item, listaDeDados);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```